# Aggrid How to trigger forEachNodeAfterFilter after rowData has changed without changing the filter string

Tags: ag-grid

I have a custom label where I display the number of filtered rows ("currently displaying x out of y results").
When I change the filter string it works great because I use

```
(filterChanged)="onFilterChanged($event)"
```

And in my ts file:

```
onFilterChanged() {
    let filteredRowCount = 0;
    this.gridApi.forEachNodeAfterFilter(() => {
        filteredRowCount++;
    });
    this.numberToShow = filteredRowCount;
}
```

(the variable I am bound to is numberToShow).

I have a refresh button which causes this.rowData to get updated. If the user has applied a filter and refreshes the data I have no programmatical way of knowing how many rows are currently shown.

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve it by having `newRowsAction: 'keep'` in `filterParams` of each of your columns.
Then on click of refresh button, you should add

```
if (this.gridApi.isAnyFilterPresent()) {
  this.gridApi.onFilterChanged() 
}
```

This should forcefully trigger your `filterChanged` logic

Comment: Thanks It is useful for my development

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else ends up here the `agTotalAndFilteredRowCountComponent` status bar component can do this out of the box (enterprise) https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/status-bar/